# SQL Server "There is already an object named"

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create table X, but I get :

> There is already an object named 'X' in the database

I try to find the object 'X' which already exists as such :

```
Select 
    [name] as ObjectName, Type as ObjectType
From
    Sys.Objects
Where 
    1 = 1
    and [Name] Like '%X%'
```

I get an empty result set.

**Note:** I already checked other stack overflow similar question, but this case isn't related to Entity Framework, and isn't about me not realizing that I already have the object in the database, and isn't about temp tables.

So what is going on?

Comment: Did you `use` the correct database before selecting from `sys.objects`?

Comment: Yes. The queries are against the same database.\

Comment: Show us the query you use to create the object.

Comment: Does `object_id('X')` return an id? If so, find more about it with [`objectproperty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/objectproperty-transact-sql). Also note `sys.objects` [does not contain DDL triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql).

Comment: try this `if object_id('t1','u') is not null
drop table t1
go
` then create table

Comment: No trace of the object in database, or any database for that matter. I even Used redgate's sql search just to make sure. And same result. 
The create table just won't pass no matter what I try.

Comment: By any chance, is "X" referred here a KeyWord?

Comment: object_id('t1','u') is null. 

@Praveen Table X if you are interested is : "tbl_AdmD1_BirthCertificate"
so no.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri 
The creation script is standard and nothing unique about it, I don't see how this would help. It starts with a Use statement and then create statement.

Comment: @Cogent maybe there is something you missed. Any small issue. The way you describe it, it should work. But it doesn't! Anyway :)

Comment: Maybe the object exists but you don't have permission to see it.

Comment: @MartinSmith Good point, will investigate further.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri It turned out I was wrong undermining the table creation script. Though the confusion was caused by the confusing error from sqlserver. The actuall issue wasn't object already exists, rather a type-o in the column definitions (extra comma). My mistake, you were right.

Comment: Very good that you found out the issue! :)

Comment: knowing what that typo actually was (the "extra comma") would help others

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TableName') IS NOT NULL
SELECT 'EXISTS',  OBJECT_ID('TableName') AS 'Obj_Id'
ELSE
SELECT 'NOT EXISTS', '' AS 'Obj_Id'
```